# Three related(?) Outlook 2013 issues?

Tags: exchange, microsoft-outlook-2013

I have a colleague who reported three, perhaps related, Outlook related issues. Our Outlook interfaces our on-site Exchange server. We have all but eliminated the possibility of a server-side issue. The issues are as follows:

1. Two days ago, all of the emails in the Sent Items folder disappeared and were later discovered in the Deleted Items folder. This only happened once and we were able to restore the emails.
2. Occasionally when she visits the Sent Items folder, she discovers that a handful of emails are available and the rest have been moved to a local archive and there's a message that says (approximately) "click here to see the archived emails"
3. Yesterday, some of the emails she believed to have deleted reappeared in the Inbox.

We have checked for inadvertent Outlook rules or any deviation in retention policies, but did not find anything suspicious.

The only theory I have at this point is that the keyboard may be faulty. For example, if the Control key occasionally gets stuck, I can see how pressing other keys can trigger various shortcuts. But she thinks this is highly unlikely since her keyboard appears to be quite reliable.

What other ideas can we explore?

Update: I suggested to my colleague that we replace the keyboard to rule out its being the culprit and received the response below. So I'm at a slight loss for what to explore next. Any suggestions?

> My keyboard is less than a year old and I have taken it into the Apple store to have them check and verify that the keys are functional and there are no issues.  I have the report from them at home.  Perhaps a better point of focus is why the "Your Sent Emails have been archived" notification started the week before the sent email mailbox was impaired.  Coincidences like this are highly suspect.  And now I am no longer receiving that notice.  Rather than spending more time on the forensics, I am focused on what I can control - my work.  If more problems occur, I'll just communicate clearly, honestly, responsibly, and expansively my disappointment and hope it isn’t disruptive to the firm (and to me).
>
> Check into the Archiving message.  That’s where I suspect you will find the answer.  It isn’t my keyboard.
>
> Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you have auto-archive configuration setup

Comment: You might also start to rebuild the Outlook mail profile at first (as Walmart) already mentioned. Then also check if the MS Office version is up to date, install any Servicepack which is missing here and all MS office Updates.

Comment: The easiest thing to do to narrow down the source of the issues would be to have her log in to a new computer and use it for a few days. If there are no issues, then it's likely her profile on the old computer is the problem. If you don't have a new computer, BACKUP the old Outlook profile and then delete it and have her run Outlook to recreate the profile as others have mentioned. Your symptoms all sound profile-related, and it's likely a relatively easy fix.